# AsyncTask and getting/updating Data

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I can easily get data from the database.. But because Asynctask runs in the background, it has not downloaded the data before i call my update() method.

Example.

MyGetDataFromDatebaseCall();

UpdateSomething();

So here's my question. How can you make the UpdateSomething() method wait until the MyGetDatebaseCall() has downloaded alle the data?
I have made a Dialog window that pops up, so the user have to press okay to proceed and that works. I could also create 2 buttons so they call one method each. But they are such ugly solutions. I have also tried to send an instance of the Activity i was in, and making the AsyncTask class try and update the Activity class in the doInBackground, but apperently it cant be done?

Comment: why don't you call UpdateSomething() at onPostExecute method of asyncTask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call MyGetDataFromDatebaseCall() method in doInBackground() and after downloading all the data, you can call updateSomething() method in onPostExecute().
It will work fine.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but i'm new to all this. Thx for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever look at the documentation?

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```